# Why do I have to press the key twice?

Tags: javascript, html, key, keypress, onkeydown

I am making a little JS game and I am trying to make the user's input checked ASAP, so I am using the onKeyDown function. Problem is, if the answer is 5, I have to press 5, then press 5 again for it to recognize the user's input, why is this happening?

```
var btn=0
var num=""
var digits=1
function quickanswer(){
    if (document.getElementById("autocheck").checked==true&&document.getElementById("txt").value.length==digits){
        document.getElementById("dots").innerHTML = ""
        createdots()
        document.getElementById("txt").value=""
        document.getElementById("txt").focus()
        document.getElementById("txt").style.color = "#000000"
    }
}
function submitenter(){
    var keycode = window.event.keyCode;
    if (keycode == 13)
       {
       btnclick();
       }
    if (keycode < 47 || keycode > 58){
       return false;}
    }

<input id="txt" type="text" onKeyPress="return submitenter()" onKeyDown="quickanswer()"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `onKeyDown` event happens **before** the character is actually appended to the textbox.

To capture the new character use `onkeyup` event instead.

Anyway, your code is currently not cross browser.. `window.event` is not standard instead pass the event as argument to the function like this:

```
onKeyPress="return submitenter(event)"
```

Then in the function:

```
function submitenter(evt){
    //IE fix
    if (typeof evt == "undefined")
        evt = window.event;
    var keycode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    ...
```

Comment: Is there any way to get which key was pressed with the onKeyDown?

Comment: @Sean yes exactly like you get it in `submitenter` already: `var keycode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;` where "evt" is like I explained above to make it cross browser.